# Cannot find Ionic-angular module

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm Learning Ionic v4 and the template are compiled successfully. But when I change these template to components examples like this one below, It gives error that I mention below.

What did i do wrong? And if the process I made for testing alert is wrong, how can I test codes and add pages in ionic?

I would be grateful if anyone can help me learn to use ionic. I have project to deliver in 2 weeks
Thanks

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
export class BasicPage {

  constructor(public alerCtrl: AlertController) { }

  doAlert() {
    let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
      title: 'New Friend!',
      message: 'Your friend, Obi wan Kenobi, just approved your 
friend request!',
      buttons: ['Ok']
    });
    alert.present()
  }

}
```

> ERROR in 
>   ./src/app/tab3/tab3.module.ts 16:58- 
>   66
>   [ng] "export 'Tab3Page' was not 
>   found in './tab3.page'
>   [ng] ERROR in 
>   ./src/app/tab3/tab3.module.ts 18:23- 
>   31
>   [ng] "export 'Tab3Page' was not 
>   found in './tab3.page'
>   [ng] ERROR in 
>   ./src/app/tab3/tab3.page.ts
>   [ng] Module not found:
>   ./src/app/tab3/tab3.page.ts
>   [ng] Module not found: Error: Can't 
>   resolve 'ionic-angular' in 
>   'C:\Users\ASUS\Ionic\
>   app\src\app\tab3'
>   [ng] Time: 797ms
>   [ng] i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
>   [ng]
>   [ng] ERROR in 
>   src/app/tab3/tab3.module.ts(6,10): 
>   error TS2305: Module 
>   '"C:/Users/ASUS/Ionic/app
>   /src/app/tab3/tab3.page"' has no 
>   exported member 'Tab3Page'.
>   [ng] 
>   src/app/tab3/tab3.page.ts(3,33): 
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 
>   'ionic-angular'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various update in Ionic4.

```
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';  // Ionic 4

import { AlertController } from 'ionic/angular';  // Ionic 3
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add page using command line it will wire all things

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/generate

```
ionic generate page your_page_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your tab3 component(**tab3.page.ts**) is ok but there is problems with your tab3 module(**tab3.module.ts** same folder). Best way to get rid of this error is deleting tab3 page and recreating page with below command.

```
ionic generate page tab3
```

Answer (score 0):

update this.

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

it will be

```
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

In ionic4, its changed that's why you are getting an error.

[visit this link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert)